# How can I separate length and width?

Tags: excel, split

I have a field called Image Size that has values like:

```
12x12
20x8
20x8
20x8
20x8
10x8
10x8
36x12
27x27
39.75x20
```

How would I go about putting the length in one column and the width in another column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two functions you can use to split text in Excel for this purpose: `LEFT` and `RIGHT`. These functions take the text to split and the number of characters to take from one side. For instance, `LEFT("asdf", 2)` would take 2 characters from the string `"asdf"`, starting from the left side.

You can combine these functions with the `SEARCH` function to find the "x" in the middle, so in each row, you would put the image in column 1,

```
=LEFT(A1, SEARCH("x",A1,1))
```

in column 2, and

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("x",A1,1))
```

in column 3. (These examples are for row A.)

Reference: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/split-text-among-columns-by-using-functions-HA010102341.aspx

**EDIT**: As pointed out in a comment by the OP, the first formula should be

```
=LEFT(A1, SEARCH("x",A1,1) - 1)
```

so that the "x" isn't included

Comment: The first formula almost works, but it is displaying the x with the value.

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1** , use:

```
=--LEFT(A1,FIND("X",A1)-1)
```

and

```
=--MID(A1,FIND("X",A1)+1,9999)
```